# What does "rank dishonesty" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've encountered this phrase online and couldn't find a dictionary definition for the phrase. What does "rank dishonesty" mean, and especially what does the word "rank" mean in this context?

According to a dictionary, 'rank' means 'unpleasant', 'strongly', or 'extremely' which are different from each other but all make sense in this context. I want to first confirm if this is a set phrase that has a idiomatic meaning beyond the literal one. Secondly, if it is not a set phrase, which meaning of 'rank' is the right one here?

(My first impression, which is very likely wrong, is it means someone with lower social/military rank being deliberately dishonest (backstabbing) against someone with a higher rank.)

Comment: Try [*rank, adj*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/rank_3).

Comment: @NS.X.: Without checking, I can't explain why *rank* has meanings including both *grade, order, class* and *rotten, offensive, extreme*. Perhaps it's connected to the idiomatic usage whereby we say something [is of the **first** rank](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is+of+the+first+rank%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but that usually means "the best", rather than "the worst".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I checked the OED, and it seems that they're etymologically two different words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To begin with, the noun *rank* has nothing to do with the adjective *rank*.

The noun is of French origin (possibly Frankish ultimately) and originally denoted a series or line of things (*range* has the same origin); then specifically a line of warriors or soldiers (whence our 'rank and file'); then the successive lines, the first, second, third ranks, and so forth, in which soldiers are deployed; and finally, by way of one's position in the front, middle or rear rank, one's grade or standing.

The adjective *rank* is of Germanic origin; the precise line of descent is obscure but it seems originally to have denoted various attributes of the noble warrior: *proud*, *haughty*, *rebellious*, *strong*, *vigorous*, *full-grown*. In ME the martial connection faded and the word became used particularly of undesired and excessive strength, vigor and abundance; it was extended to vegetation (we still speak of 'rank weeds') and to  loathsome behavior and smells (*O mine offense is rank* says Claudius); eventually it acquired such a strong negative connotation that came to mean 'corrupt, foul, festering', and eventually simply 'extremely (offensive)'.

See the [Oxford English Dictionary, 1st edition](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt108murruoft#page/142/mode/2up).

When your source writes of *rank dishonesty* it probably does not intend any one of these later senses but (at some level) all of them simultaneously: extremely gross, corrupt, loathsome dishonesty.

Comment: Funny, but I had instinctively imagined that the adjectival 'rank' was somehow descended from the verb 'reek', for odor, and was thinking along the conjugational lines of 'stink' -> 'stank', 'reek' ... (somehow) -> 'rank'.

Answer (score 4):

"Rank," in this context means "downright" or "complete." So the expression means, "complete dishonesty."

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself in the question. As an adjective, "rank" means "strong" or "extreme" in a negative sense. We often say "it was a rank smell", meaning something smelled very bad. So "rank dishonesty" is extreme dishonesty.